# I need guidance to learn spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-development-server

I have been working on mobile platforms j2me , android , etc. I have sound knowledge of core java and android. but now the situation is like I need to take on projects on spring and hibernate framework.

Can someone suggest me how should I start my preparation. What all technologies I need to understand before starting spring and hibernate?

Comment: just have a hang of j2ee and you should be ready to hit spring and hibernate carte blanche

Comment: I think posting this over on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might get more attention as it's more on education rather than solving a technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Step-By-Step Spring tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/). It's a little outdated but it should help you get started with Spring.

This [blog](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html) has some good examples of Spring/hibernate which I have found very helpful.

[Here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/42-integrating-spring-framework-with-hibernate-orm-framewo-1.html) is another tutorial/sample application. At the bottom of the page you will find some more links that could help you.

Good Luck!